# How do I solve this monadT relationship in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I met this question today while learning haskell monad transformers.
Assume I have a type `instance Monad m => Monad (CustomT m)`.

If there's a function `f :: CustomT IO Int`, and there's `g :: IO (Maybe Int)`.

How do I access the `Int` of `g` in `f`?

I tried something like

```
f = do
  mVal <- g
```

This didn't work because `f` is under `CustomT IO` monad while `g` is under `MaybeT IO` monad.

And then I tried

```
f = do
  mVal <- return g
```

This seems to work but `mVal` is `IO (Maybe Int)` type, I eventually get nested `IO` like `CustomT IO (IO something)`

Is there a way to get that `Int` or `Maybe Int` out in `f`?

What knowledge is involved? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `f :: CustomT IO Maybe` doesn't really make sense. What is the kind of CustomT? Based on that, it would have to be `(* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> *`, which isn't a monad transformer in the traditional sense of the word. Do you mean `f :: CustomT IO (Maybe Int)`?

Comment: Sorry, I was too confused. I think I meant something like `f :: CustomT IO a` where `a` is a concrete type, like `Int` for example. (probably a bad example, but does it make sense?)

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, Jeremy's answer is what you want. But let's see if we can work with your specific case here. We have `f :: CustomT IO Int` and `g :: IO (Maybe Int)`, given that there exist some instances to the effect of `instance Monad m => Monad (CustomT m)` and `instance MonadTrans CustomT`.

And what you want is to get at the `Int` inside of a `g` within the context of `CustomT IO`. Since we're inside of `CustomT`, we can basically strip that layer off trivially. Like Jeremy says, use `lift` to get rid of that.

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

So now we have `CustomT IO (Maybe Int)`. Like I said, we're inside a `do`-block, so using Haskell's bind (`<-`) syntax gets rid of the monad layer temporarily. Thus, we're dealing with `Maybe Int`. To get from `Maybe Int` to `Int`, the usual approach is to use `maybe`

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

This provides a default value just in case the `Maybe Int` is actually `Nothing`. So, for instance, `maybe 0 id` is a function that takes a `Maybe Int` and yields the inner `Int`, or `0` if the value is `Nothing`. So, in the end, we have:

```
f = do
  mVal <- maybe 0 id $ lift g
  -- Other code
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `Control.Monad.Trans` you have this definition for monad transformers:

```
class MonadTrans (t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *) where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

Which means that if `CustomT` has been defined properly you can do this:

```
f = do
  mVal <- lift g
```